# How to add a new row inside the table with the addition of @html.helper

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

When pressing the new row button it should add a new line with the `@html.helper`.

```
@model  List<Table.Invoice_Details>
  <table id="tbl_invoice" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>code item</th>
        <th>name item:</th>
        <th>unit:</th>
        <th>quantity:</th>
        <th>price:</th>
        <th>total:</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach (Table.Invoice_Details Loop in Model)
      {
        <tr>
          <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(modelitem => Loop.Item_Period.Item.Code_Item, new { id = "Code_Item", @class = "form-control item_code" , href= "javascript:;" })
          </td>
          <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => Loop.Item_Period.Item.Name_Item, new { id = "Name_Item_" + Loop.ID_Invoice_Details, @class = "form-control item_name", disabled = "disabled" })
          </td>
          <td>
             @{    
              if (Loop.Item_Period != null)
              {
                var a = (from i in Loop.Item_Period.Item.Item_Unit select i.Unit).ToList();
                @Html.DropDownList("Unit", new SelectList(a, "ID_Unit", "Name_Unit"), new { id = "Name_Unit_" + Loop.ID_Invoice_Details, @class = "form-control", width = "120px" })
              }
              else
              {   
                List<Table.Unit> unit = new List<Table.Unit>();
                @Html.DropDownList("Unit", new SelectList(unit, "ID_Unit", "Name_Unit"), new { id = "Name_Unit_" + Loop.ID_Invoice_Details, @class = "form-control", width = "120px" })
              }
            }
          </td>
          <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(modelitem => Loop.Quantity, new { id = "Quantity_" + Loop.ID_Invoice_Details, style = "width:60px;" })
          </td>
          <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(modelitem => Loop.Spical_Rate, new { style = "width:80px" })
          </td>
          <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(modelitem => Loop.Total, new { id = "Total_Money_W_Taxes", style = "width:80px" })
          </td>
        </tr>
      }
    </tbody>
</table>       
<button>new row</button>
```

I used the following code using the `insertRow` command but it doesn't add `@html.helper` widgets

```
function addRows() {

  var table = document.getElementById('tbl_invoice'),
    row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length),
    cell1 = row.insertCell(0),
    cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

  cell1.innerHTML = 'Cell 1';
  cell2.innerHTML = 'Cell 2';
}
```

Comment: You're mixing server-side Razor (`@Html`) with client-side JavaScript `function addRows() {`.   You *could* make an ajax request to an MVC action on your controller to return just a new row, or you could clone an existing row (in js) and make corresponding updates (ie update the IDs (although you *probably* don't need the `id=` and should just update the generated `name=`)).

Comment: Thank you brother, can you explain how you used the AJAX route